# Visual Studio 2013 git merge tool does not seem to work, no toolbar and only one file shows

Tags: git, visual-studio, merge

I try to resolve conflicts using VS 2013 and using a git repo.
When I click on the [Merge] button, only one file is shown, and no merge tools in the top.

Please see the attached picture.

What am I missing?
For the same repo, same solution, my Visual Studio 2012 works correctly.

Thx in advance.

[image: My VS window after the left side [Merge] button pressed]

Comment: Is that a `.cshtml` file by any chance?

Comment: No, it is a regular .cs